# DominoView dataSource with keys and search

Tags: search, xpages

In Java I have code:

```
View view = database.getView("XXX");
ViewEntryCollection result = view.getAllEntriesByKey(vec, true);
result.FTSearch(query);
return result;
```

But its return **ViewEntryCollection** and i can't use **entry.ColumnName** in repeater, only **entry.getColumnValues** and **entry.getDocument().getItemValue()**

Best way for me - it is use dominoView as Data Source with parameters **keys** and **search**, but if set property search, then property keys is ignored

May be you know other way?

Comment: Is there a reason for avoiding `entry.getColumnValues()`? If it's for performance, to access a specific column value via #{entry.columnName}, my understanding is it will still have to call `entry.getColumnValues()`, so I wouldn't expect a performance benefit, certainly not one that's perceptible. If it's readability, OpenNTF Domino API adds `entry.getColumnValue(string)`, allowing you to pass a column name.

Comment: Thank for answer, Paul! In full source code view is calculated and I can't be sure that the order of the columns will be the same. Domino API is good, but in my compant It is difficult to install additional software on the server

Comment: OpenNTF Domino API, like Extension Library releases, is "installed" by the admin uploading a few "notes" (i.e. documents) into an UpdateSite.nsf. Using Domino for more than email will mean developers (probably less experienced in Domino dev than contributors to ODA like Nathan Freeman) adding more (unsupported by IBM) notes into databases on the server and end users adding documents into the database as well. If it's an issue of support, RedPill announced support for it a while back http://redpilldevelopment.com/red-pill-announces-support-for-openntf-domino-api/ & others would also support it